how to access Google Analytics 4 properties on windows document?
I know there is a medium property from Google Analytics 4 like this if a page is viewed

can I possibly access that medium on DOM or windows document in browser? I mean I can acess the page refferer using
windows.document.referrer

in inspect element, how to do the same thing for medium ?

It's kind of a calculated value:

If someone visited your website without utm parameters.
If someone visited your website from other domain.

Then GA4 would treat this traffic as referral for medium, the domain for source.
From the screenshot you provided. It's a traffic coming from l.instagram.com.

hi, thanks for the reply Darrel. but I want to know how get that referral value on Google Chrome Dev Tool, something like windows.document.mediumOrSomethingHere

It's the window.document.referrer that you already guess. Does the value seems not correct for you?

what I really need is to get 'medium' data, I have no problem to get referrer data

Okay got. You want to know how to get the referral as string value not the field right? There is no this value in chrome devtool. Again it's calculated in GA4 background I think they don't store this value in the browser.
